# PHP - Invalid JSON payload received google exception

Tags: php, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am having trouble adding/updating new column data on my google sheet reports.

[image]

Anyone has experienced this error?

`Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"0\" at 'data.values[21]': Cannot find field`

Thank you

Comment: what did you sent?

Comment: I thought that in your question, when you provide your current script and explain the current issue of your script, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask].  Then edit your question and include [example] and not as an image please.

Comment: Can you share the JSON you sent as well as more data about what you're trying to access (ideally the code along with the endpoint)

Comment: Looks like you sent some invalid JSON, or at least the JSON you sent didn't match the structure of what Google is expecting. Without a [mre] of the issue including relevant code and data, there's not much we can suggest except to tell you that you need to double-check what you're sending very carefully in relation to the specific information provided to you in the error message. I'm not familiar with Google Sheets API particularly, but from the error message it looks like in your JSON you've specified some fields which Google thinks don't exist in the sheet you're accessing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same error and in my case the problem was that I was passing a PHP null value in the range values of the call to `service.spreadsheets().values().append()`.

Replacing all null values with an empty string `''` did the trick.